# Question concerning Stirling’s Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

From Nielsen & Chuang, page 55:

> The basic intuition for this decrease in resources required can be understood quite easily. Suppose the source emitting states $|0\rangle$ with probability $p$ and $(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)/\sqrt2$ with probability $1 — p$ is used a large number $n$ times. Then by the law of large numbers, with high probability the source emits about $np$ copies of $|0\rangle$ and $n(1 — p)$ copies of $(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)/\sqrt2$. That is, it has the form
>   $$|0\rangle^{\otimes np} \left( \frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt2} \right)^{\otimes n(1-p)},\tag{1.60}\label{1.60}$$
>   up to re-ordering of the systems involved. Suppose we expand the product of $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ terms on the right hand side. Since $n(1 — p)$ is large, we can again use the law of large numbers to deduce that the terms in the product will be roughly one-half $|0\rangle$s and one-half $|1\rangle$s. That is, the $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ product can be well approximated by a superposition of states of the form
>   $$|0\rangle^{\otimes n(1-p)/2} |1\rangle^{\otimes n(1-p)/2}.\tag{1.61}\label{1.61}$$
>   Thus the state emitted by the source can be approximated as a superposition of terms of
>   the form
>   $$|0\rangle^{\otimes n(1+p)/2} |1\rangle^{\otimes n(1-p)/2}.\tag{1.62}\label{1.62}$$
>   How many states of this form are there? **Roughly $n$ choose $n(1 + p)/2$, which by Stirling's approximation is equal to $N \equiv 2^{nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]}$**. A simple compression method then is to label all states of the form (\ref{1.62}) $|c_1\rangle$ through $|c_N\rangle$. It is possible to perform a unitary transform on the $n$ qubits emitted from the source that takes $|c_j\rangle$ to $|j\rangle|0\rangle^{\otimes n-nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]}$, since $j$ is an $nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]$ bit number. The  compression operation is to perform this unitary transformation, and then drop the final $n-nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]$ qubits, leaving a compressed state of $nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]$ qubits. To decompress we append the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n-nH[(1+p)/2,(1-p)/2]}$ to the compressed state, and perform the inverse unitary transformation.

I don’t understand the emphasized part. How to obtain the result $N$ by Stirling’s approximation? I’m not familiar with Stirling’s approximation. Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: Have you tried the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @E.P. Sorry but someone has corrected it. I will type next time.

Comment: @BySymmetry Yes but I'm still a little confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity that's being described, $n$ [choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_function) $n(1+p)/2$ (also known as a binomial coefficient), is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
where you take $k = \frac12 n(1+p)$. [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which reads
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n},
$$
can then be applied to the three factorials in the binomial coefficient. The rest is simple algebra and it is really up to you to implement.

Comment: I've calculated it but the result was a little different. I'm wondering whether the $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ part can be ignored? If I use $n! \sim \frac{n^n}{e^n}$, the answer is exactly the N defined by the author. But if $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}$, $n$ choose $n(1+p)/2$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}\sqrt{(1+p)(1-p)}}N$. Or do you think it's just a problem concerning the definition of N?

Comment: If the result you quote can be obtained ignoring the $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ then that is likely what the authors mean. The square root is the least important part of the formula, and it is ultimately a minor correction to the core $(n/e)^n$ (since it provides only a measly $n^{-1/2}$ moderation to the $n^n$ growth); whether you can ignore it or not depends on how precise you want to be. For more details on the subtleties of the Stirling formula as regards convergence, see the linked Wikipedia article as well as most calculus textbooks.